# File_get_content works on the local server, but not hosted on server

Tags: php, download, codeigniter-2, file-get-contents, codeigniter-url

I am working on download functionality in code-igniter as i am newbie to the framework

I am facing problem with this functionality which is working fine on localhost but failed to work on server..

As describing my problem

**Here is the download function in my controller**

```
    public function download()
 {
 $uri=$this->uri->segment(2);
 $check=array();
 $check['q_id']=$uri;
 $img=  $this->prototype_model->get_data($check,'orders');//getting data from db
 $imgname=$img['stl_image'];//stores the image name from result array
 $data = file_get_contents(base_url()."assets/upload_img/".$imgname);// Read the file's contents
 $name = $imgname;//name to download file
   force_download($name, $data);           
  }
```

As i searched on SO for solution ,i found that **allow_url_fopen = on** and i checked on my server about this ,it was fine.

I am able to get the data based on uri segment, but file_get_content not taking the image name and the server returns some errors as follows

**Error 1**

```
     Severity: Notice
     Message:  file_get_contents() [function.file-get-contents]: send of 30 bytes failed with errno=104 Connection reset by peer
     Filename: controllers/prototype.php
     Line Number: 796
```

**Error-2**

```
     Severity: Notice
     Message:  file_get_contents() [function.file-get-contents]: send of 2 bytes failed with errno=32 Broken pipe
     Filename: controllers/prototype.php
     Line Number: 796
```

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Should you not get the file based on the local directory not the domain. file_get_contents(/var/www/something/something);

Comment: @TomChew-headMillard what do you mean? can you explain little more..

Comment: Well im not overly sure with out looking at the code but does baseURL not return the domain name of the site?

Comment: I am able to get the base url as site domain name but the file_get_contents not reading the file .. i think that's the problem, what do you say?

Comment: is the file locally stored if so, then i would use the directory. You might have to fiddle around a bit - http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/directory_helper.html

Comment: if you use the domain name that normally triggers a http request to retrieve a file which is what you use curl for.

Comment: so i have to use folder path instead of base url.. am i correct

Comment: yes - this is how file_get_contents work using it with a url normally results in an error.

Comment: Ok..let me try with the directory path

Comment: Can you show me how to give path on server.. as i am using as 
file_get_contents("www.3d-prototype.co.uk/test/assets/upload_img/".$imgname);

Comment: But it showing error no such file or directory.. what i am missing in it.. I know this was simple , as i am new to framework

Comment: its quite difficult to do this since i don't know your system set up, using functions like getcwd() or dirname(__dir__) and even the codeigniter frame work helpers should help with this.

Comment: this is not your answer but you can use curl instead of file_get_contents(): http://blogs.digitss.com/php/php-downloading-a-file-from-secure-website-https-using-curl/